# STL containers' difference_type typedef

Tags: c++, stl

I noticed STL containers (including `vector`, `list`, etc.) have a `difference_type` typedef, which is usually an alias for `std::ptrdiff_t`.

What is it used for? It is used by any member functions?

Answer (score 2):

It's used to compute difference between iterators. 
For example `cont.end() - cont.begin().`
It's not used directly by stl container, but is widely used by iterator library.
Example:

```
template< class InputIt >
typename std::iterator_traits<InputIt>::difference_type 
    distance( InputIt first, InputIt last );
```